# Bash Shellshock

Tags: exploit, shellshock, bash

I am trying to find out if my devices are vulnerable to bash shellshock. I have run the commands found on https://shellshocker.net. It seems my devices are both susceptible to only one of the vulnerabilities - Exploit 7 CVE-2014-6277, but I am not sure. The result of me running this command is "Segmentation fault", then on a new line "vulnerable". Can anyone tell me if this means I am indeed vulnerable and how to patch this? Also to be sure, is there any way I can run a script that tries to exploit this vulnerability?

Comment: Can you post the command you're running since that site is not working.

Comment: Thank you for responding. I am sorry but I made a mistake in my post, the site actually runs over https so its https://shellshocker.net. However the command is as follows: "bash -c "f() { x() { _;}; x() { _;} <<a; }" 2>/dev/null || echo vulnerable".

Comment: Try this command: _x='() { echo vulnerable; }' bash -c '_x 2>/dev/null || echo not vulnerable' The one you're posting doesn't sit quite right with me.

Answer (score 3):

Here a good way to check for Shellshock as well one of the easiest way to fix is:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install --only-upgrade bash
```

Usage: bash .sh

```
#!/bin/bash
EXITCODE=0

# CVE-2014-6271
CVE20146271=$(env 'x=() { :;}; echo vulnerable' 'BASH_FUNC_x()=() { :;}; echo vulnerable' bash -c "echo test" 2>&1 | grep 'vulnerable' | wc -l)

echo -n "CVE-2014-6271 (original shellshock): "
if [ $CVE20146271 -gt 0 ]; then
    echo -e "\033[91mVULNERABLE\033[39m"
    EXITCODE=$((EXITCODE+1))
else
    echo -e "\033[92mnot vulnerable\033[39m"
fi

# CVE-2014-6277
# it is fully mitigated by the environment function prefix passing avoidance
CVE20146277=$((shellshocker="() { x() { _;}; x() { _;} <<a; }" bash -c date 2>/dev/null || echo vulnerable) | grep 'vulnerable' | wc -l)

echo -n "CVE-2014-6277 (segfault): "
if [ $CVE20146277 -gt 0 ]; then
    echo -e "\033[91mVULNERABLE\033[39m"
    EXITCODE=$((EXITCODE+2))
else
    echo -e "\033[92mnot vulnerable\033[39m"
fi

# CVE-2014-6278
CVE20146278=$(shellshocker='() { echo vulnerable; }' bash -c shellshocker 2>/dev/null | grep 'vulnerable' | wc -l)

echo -n "CVE-2014-6278 (Florian's patch): "
if [ $CVE20146278 -gt 0 ]; then
    echo -e "\033[91mVULNERABLE\033[39m"
    EXITCODE=$((EXITCODE+4))
else
    echo -e "\033[92mnot vulnerable\033[39m"
fi

# CVE-2014-7169
CVE20147169=$((cd /tmp; rm -f /tmp/echo; env X='() { (a)=>\' bash -c "echo echo nonvuln" 2>/dev/null; [[ "$(cat echo 2> /dev/null)" == "nonvuln" ]] && echo "vulnerable" 2> /dev/null) | grep 'vulnerable' | wc -l)

echo -n "CVE-2014-7169 (taviso bug): "
if [ $CVE20147169 -gt 0 ]; then
    echo -e "\033[91mVULNERABLE\033[39m"
    EXITCODE=$((EXITCODE+8))
else
    echo -e "\033[92mnot vulnerable\033[39m"
fi

# CVE-2014-7186
CVE20147186=$((bash -c 'true <<EOF <<EOF <<EOF <<EOF <<EOF <<EOF <<EOF <<EOF <<EOF <<EOF <<EOF <<EOF <<EOF <<EOF' 2>/dev/null || echo "vulnerable") | grep 'vulnerable' | wc -l)

echo -n "CVE-2014-7186 (redir_stack bug): "
if [ $CVE20147186 -gt 0 ]; then
    echo -e "\033[91mVULNERABLE\033[39m"
    EXITCODE=$((EXITCODE+16))
else
    echo -e "\033[92mnot vulnerable\033[39m"
fi

# CVE-2014-7187
CVE20147187=$(((for x in {1..200}; do echo "for x$x in ; do :"; done; for x in {1..200}; do echo done; done) | bash || echo "vulnerable") | grep 'vulnerable' | wc -l)

echo -n "CVE-2014-7187 (nested loops off by one): "
if [ $CVE20147187 -gt 0 ]; then
    echo -e "\033[91mVULNERABLE\033[39m"
    EXITCODE=$((EXITCODE+32))
else
    echo -e "\033[92mnot vulnerable\033[39m"
fi

# CVE-2014-////
CVE2014=$(env X=' () { }; echo vulnerable' bash -c 'date' | grep 'vulnerable' | wc -l)

echo -n "CVE-2014-//// (exploit 3 on http://shellshocker.net/): "
if [ $CVE2014 -gt 0 ]; then
    echo -e "\033[91mVULNERABLE\033[39m"
    EXITCODE=$((EXITCODE+64))
else
    echo -e "\033[92mnot vulnerable\033[39m"
fi

exit $EXITCODE
```